# Emails are going to spam folder using php mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am using a simple PHP script to send mail. But my emails are going to the spam folder. Sender of the received mail in spam folder is listed as:

> mymail@gmail.com via pro10.winwinhosting.com

And the email message is showing this warning:

> Why is this message in Spam? We've found that lots of messages from
>   pro10.winwinhosting.com are spam

My PHP script looks like this:

```
$email_to = $_SESSION['email'];
$email_subject = "Mail Subject/#/ ";
$message = "Some message";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ABC <mymail@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: use googles smtp server for smtp relay 
you are relaying it through someplace else

Comment: better use php mailer for sending mail